# Traversing and Getting Nodes in Graph without Loop

Tags: sql-server, recursion, graph, graph-databases, genealogy

I have a person table which keeps some personal info. like as table below.

```
+----+------+----------+----------+--------+
| ID | name | motherID | fatherID |  sex   |
+----+------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1 | A    | NULL     | NULL     | male   |
|  2 | B    | NULL     | NULL     | female |
|  3 | C    | 1        | 2        | male   |
|  4 | X    | NULL     | NULL     | male   |
|  5 | Y    | NULL     | NULL     | female |
|  6 | Z    | 5        | 4        | female |
|  7 | T    | NULL     | NULL     | female |
+----+------+----------+----------+--------+
```

Also I keep marriage relationships between people. Like:

```
+-----------+--------+
| HusbandID | WifeID |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      2 |
|         4 |      5 |
|         1 |      5 |
|         3 |      6 |
+-----------+--------+
```

With these information we can imagine the relationship graph. Like below;

[image]

Question is: How can I get all connected people by giving any of them's ID.

For example;

- When I give ID=1, it should return to me 1,2,3,4,5,6.(order is not important)
- Likewise When I give ID=6, it should return to me 1,2,3,4,5,6.(order is not important)
- Likewise When I give ID=7, it should return to me 7.

Please attention : Person nodes' relationships (edges) may have loop anywhere of graph. Example above shows small part of my data. I mean; person and marriage table may consist thousands of rows and we do not know where loops may occur.

Smilar questions asked in :

[PostgreSQL SQL query for traversing an entire undirected graph and returning all edges found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375386/postgresql-sql-query-for-traversing-an-entire-undirected-graph-and-returning-all)
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=118319

But I can't code the working SQL. Thanks in advance. **I am using SQL Server.**

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Azure SQL Database or SQL Server 2017? Both have (limited) graph capabilities.

Comment: I tried SQL Server 2017 but I can not write a solution query.

Comment: use Neo4j :).  Or, write a sproc, keep track of each node ID that you've crossed, and for each node that you're attempting to access, check first if you've already processed it (I did this a while back and it was the only way to prevent circular processing at the time... 2 years or so ago, prior to any graph-specific functionality in RDBMs)

Answer (score 3):

From SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL DB you can use the [new graph database capabilities](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/04/20/graph-data-processing-with-sql-server-2017/) and the new `MATCH` clause to answer queries like this, eg

```
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE ( 'Person %s (%i) has mother %s (%i) and father %s (%i).', person.userName, person.personId, mother.userName, mother.personId, father.userName, father.personId ) msg
FROM dbo.persons person, dbo.relationship hasMother, dbo.persons mother, dbo.relationship hasFather, dbo.persons father
WHERE hasMother.relationshipType = 'mother'
  AND hasFather.relationshipType = 'father'
  AND MATCH ( father-(hasFather)->person<-(hasMother)-mother );
```

My results:

[image: Results]

Full script available [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/90ee6e681c2a97214645ce5c34d0b464).

For your specific questions, the current release does not include transitive closure (the ability to loop through the graph n number of times) or polymorphism (find any node in the graph) and answering these queries may involve loops, recursive CTEs or temp tables.  I have attempted this in my sample script and it works for your sample data but it's just an example - I'm not 100% it will work with other sample data.